# creating images in reST directives

Tags: python, restructuredtext

I'm trying to create a reStructuredText directive that takes it's content, creates an image based on that content using PIL, and then displays the generated image in the document. What I've done so far is subclass the image directive, create the file at a certain path (say, images/diagram.png), and then pass images/diagram.png to the image directive. The problem with this is that the file gets saved to ./images/ but the generated html document looks for it in {output_dir}/static/images/.

My question is how do I access the value of the directory that reST is using to store the output, so I can stash my image in the right place?

Comment: My temporary solution has been to save the image to a tempfile and then read the contents into a data URI, which I then pass to the image directive as the URL of the image to render, which works, but for a number of reasons, I'd rather have a real image file to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`sphinx.ext.graphviz`](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/graphviz.html) sources (e.g. [here](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/ba6608bff087/sphinx/ext/graphviz.py)), this Sphinx extension is doing almost the same thing you describe.

Comment: It looks like this can be done with sphinx, but in general, docutils doesn't know where its output is going to be sent, so it doesn't have the knowledge required to put generated files in the right place.